# Definite integral problem with $1+5^x$ in the denominator?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I solve this definite integral?

$$I =\int_{-2}^2  \frac{x^2}{1+5^x}dx $$

Is there any way to solve this integral using high school calculus.
P.S This was asked in the recently conducted CBSE Exams in India.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696823/307825